# Is winlogon.exe acting weird?

Tags: windows-7

My question just got moved to another one, which was answered but it didn't answer my question. "I noticed this process in my Task Manager. It's titled winlogon.exe and **it doesn't show my username**, it's not using any of my memory and it **doesn't have a description**. **When I click Properties it doesn't open anything**. **It doesn't show it's file location** or anything like that. Do you know what this is? Am I safe?" 
Is this normal for winlogon.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is normal behavior for winlogon.exe if you're viewing it from the task manager in Windows 7. Not sure exactly why but on Win7 it does not show a user or allow you to view properties. Win8+ does.

winlogon.exe runs with SYSTEM privileges and is responsible for user logins and user switching. It should always be located in the \system32\ directory.